# Android Studio - java module recompiled on each application recompile

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

In my Android Studio project, I've added a java module that produces a JAR file which is used by the main module. I understand that Gradle rebuilds all modules on each compile process, but it is clear that it is not needed for java modules if there is no changes since the last build.

So I want to prevent gradle from building my jar file if there is no code changes in the java module, I cannot find such option

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there're two steps to achieve what u want:

1. Ask the android plugin to pre-dex the libraries.

so you add `dexOptions` inside the `android` bracket

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
    }
}
```

2. and the other step is to make your debug build to be `minSdkVersion 21`, that way the system will build as a multi-dex application so it won't need to merge your dexed library into the APK.

There's a whole section on the dev page about it https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#dev-build, but what you want to do is add `productFlavors` inside the `android` bracket

```
android {
 productFlavors {
        // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
        dev {
            // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
            // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
            minSdkVersion YOUR_APP_MINIMUM_HERE 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, actually my problem is not to prevent merging the JAR file in the APK, I want to prevent regeneration of the JAR itself, I guess the only option is to remove the module and add the JAR as a library

Comment: That's what the pre-dex option will do. It will compile once and then only if changed or if you clean the project

Comment: Ok, so the multi-dex application part is not needed, right?

Comment: It's not needed, but it helps speeding up development time